# Who is the final boss of Terraria?

Tags: terraria

So I'm trying to figure this out: who is the final boss of terraria?

Answer (score 9):

As of version 1.3.0.1, the [Moon Lord](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Moon_Lord) is the final boss of the game, requiring the defeat of the Golem to begin summoning. It's the last boss in the progression sequence from the Wall of Flesh. The Moon Lord can be summoned by using the [Celestial Sigil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Sigil), or by defeating a number of other enemies and events in the following sequence:

1. Defeat the [Cultists](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cultist) that spawn at the Dungeon entrance after beating the Golem.
2. Defeat the [Lunatic Cultist](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lunatic_Cultist).
3. Defeat the four [Celestial Towers](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Tower) in the [Lunar Events](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lunar_Events).
4. About one minute after the final Tower is defeated, the [Moon Lord](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Moon_Lord) will spawn.

If you fail (or succeed) to defeat the Moon Lord, you'll need to begin the process again from the beginning to summon him once more (or use a Celestial Sigil, as mentioned).

---

The Console and Mobile releases of the game don't currently have the Moon Lord implemented, nor any of the other enemies in the above list. Therefore, in terms of progression, the "final boss" on those platforms would currently be considered the [Golem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem). Both platforms have a unique boss which cannot be encountered in the PC version named [Ocram](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ocram), which is considered to be the hardest boss on those platforms, but it can be summoned as soon as all three mechanical bosses are defeated, and thus can't really be considered the final boss.

Answer (score 3):

Dungeon Guardian is the hardest boss. All damage dealt to Dungeon Guardian is reduced to 1 and he has 9999 HP. He also instantly kills anyone without the maximum armor possible, even then, it only takes one more hit. He also flies and can pass through walls.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon_Guardian

Edit: This question has since been edited to make my answer completely incorrect. Please refer to [Mike Kellogg's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/258728/124825).

Comment: The Dungeon Guardian isn't hard, because you *can't* fight him in the normal fashion. He's just a tedious puzzle "boss."

Comment: @MikeKellogg Interesting, what is "the normal fashion" in which we defeat bosses?

Comment: If you honestly don't understand my meaning, you may wish to research the term [Puzzle Boss](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PuzzleBoss). (Warning: TV Tropes link.) To be more explicit, the Dungeon Guardian is intended to be undefeatable, so you have to engage in special tactics simply to not die instantly.

Comment: @MikeKellogg If it is intended to be undefeatable, why do they have a unique item that only he drops? Also, from the very article you linked: "The inversion to Puzzle Boss is Damage-Sponge Boss, which has no trickery at all and simply is worn down through brute force." Every single boss in Terraria is kite and damage, how is Dungeon Guardian any different?

Comment: It drops an item to fill the negative possibility space that would otherwise be left. The item was added well after the monster was introduced, in response to the fact that people were managing to kill the monster which was not intended to be killable. The item dropped is entirely cosmetic, basically an achievement.

Comment: And yes, while it says Damage-Sponge is usually the opposite of Puzzle, this is a rare overlap, in that the puzzle is figuring out how to survive long enough to even *start* working through its excessive HP value. Other bosses don't kill you in a single hit if you're reasonably equipped for when you first encounter them. The Dungeon Guardian is largely unkillable without equipment from further in the game than when you can fight it, or extremely specific setups. Not something any random otherwise-feasible setup can do.

Comment: Pretty sure he asked for the final boss, not the hardest.

Comment: @D.Tanya Look at the edit history.

Comment: @nukeforum Oooh didn't see that thanks for pointing out